# How does `write` mode on a `RwLock` work if it isn't mutable?

Tags: rust, rwlock

So, I was writing some code and apparently R.A. didn't warn me about some erroneous stuff I had written in regards to how ownership works with lambdas.
So, a friend helped me rewrite some of my code, and this is just a play example, but their new code boils down to this:

```rust
let vec = Rc::new(RwLock::new( Vec::new() ));
let vec_rc = vec.clone();
let my_lambda = || -> () {
  vec_rc.write().unwrap().push(/* ... */);
}
```

But what I don't understand is how this works if `vec_rc` isn't `mut`.
From my prior knowledge, mutable in Rust cascades; in other words, if the "master-containing" object is immutable the rest will have to be too.

Could I please get some clarity as to what goes on under the hood?
Or is their code erroneous too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From my prior knowledge, mutable in Rust cascades; in other words, if the "master-containing" object is immutable the rest will have to be too.

This is almost always true... Until we consider [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html).

Interior mutability is exactly about that: changing a value through a shared reference. Moreover, while there are other shared references to it. The basic interior mutability primitive is [`UnsafeCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html), but there are multiple abstractions built on top of it - one of them is `RwLock` (you can see [it secretly contains an `UnsafeCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.61.0/src/std/sync/rwlock.rs.html#81)).

As a side note, `Rc<RwLock<T>>` is almost always wrong: `Rc` is non thread safe, which defeats the whole purpose of `RwLock`. If you just need shared mutable stated over one thread, use [`Rc<RefCell<T>>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html). It is much more performant and can't block (so no deadlock debugging, just a simple panic if something went wrong).

Comment: Thanks!  
I was unaware there was such a concept.

Comment: Slightly unrelated, but:
Is there a way to make custom types with interior mutability (without `RefCell`)?

Comment: @KattyT.enbycat. Sure, just include one of the existing types in them. If you need really bare metal you can use `UnsafeCell`, but it requires `unsafe` and I really don't recommend it until you'll be proficient with Rust.

Comment: I *just* edited my question because I realized it wasn't clear. - But if there isn't a way, it'd be interesting to know how `UnsafeCell` itself pulls this off. It seems like a normal `struct` to me.

Comment: @KattyT.enbycat. Ah, I understand. `UnsafeCell` is a magic: the compiler knows it ([it is marked `#[lang = "unsafe_cell"]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.61.0/src/core/cell.rs.html#1837), `lang` means a special type known to the compiler) and treats it specifically. You cannot emulate that for your structs.

Comment: I see. - I was thinking there was some magic.
Alright. Thanks for the help.